# С помощью какой библиотеки Java войти на сайте?

Tags: php, java

Немного нубский вопрос, но всё же возникла такая задача. Нужно залогиниться на сайте. 
Вход на сайте выглядит так:

```
<input name="login">
<input type="hidden" name="lreseted" value="0">
<input name="pass" type="password">
<input type=hidden name="preseted" value=0>
```

Дайте статьи по Джаве или пример, по которому это можно осуществить. Нужно чтобы парсить страницу.

Comment: В Гугле забанили?

Comment: Какая к черту джава? понятия не путай. есть JS а есть Java тебе что нужно то?

Comment: Ну судя по вопросам автора, скорее всего Java (для android) для "тонкого" клиента. приложенный код жесть, в плане отношения к вопросу (можно было бы и выпилить ненужное)

Comment: HttpClient не подходит? Вообще надо смотреть как вообще устроен сайт, лучше бы конечно было, если бы было api

Comment: @Romanzi исправляется... старые каменты удалил, минус вернул, вопрос открыл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Типа такого (на основе HttpClient):

```
public void postData() {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://hashcode.ru");

    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nvp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

        nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "username"));
        nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", "password"));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvp));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```